# Kotlin filter lambda array using iteration index

Tags: arrays, lambda, kotlin

I would like to filter an array into an array of every nth item. For examples:

```
fun getNth(array: Array<Any>, n: Int): Array<Any> {
    val newList = ArrayList<Any>()
    for  (i in 0..array.size) {
        if (i % n == 0) {
            newList.add(array[i])
        }
    }
    return newList.toArray()
}
```

Is there an idiomatic way to do this using for example Kotlin's .filter() and without A) provisioning a new ArrayList and B) manually iterating with a for/in loop?

Comment: Just a comment, the code above is just Java masked in a Kotlin file, my recommendation is to you try to look Kotlin code in a different way, this will help you to use everything that we have available.

Comment: Absolutely. This is why I asked the question.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

`filterIndexed` function is suited exactly for this case:

```
array.filterIndexed { index, value -> index % n == 0 }
```

Answer (score 13):

Use Array.withIndex():

https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/with-index.html:

```
array.withIndex().filter { (i, value) -> i % n == 0 }.map { (i, value) -> value }
```