# How to remove item from ArrayList in Kotlin

Tags: arrays, kotlin

```
var arrayone: ArrayList<String> = arrayListOf("a","b","c")

val arraytwo:ArrayList<String> = arrayListOf(arrayone.removeAt(0))

for (item in arraytwo) {
  println(item)
}
```

I just want to remove item from the first array and make a new array.  But this just prints one item at index 0

Comment: use `arrayone.subList(1)` instead of `arrayListOf(arrayone.removeAt(0))`

Comment: `removeAt` returns the removed element. You're making a new list with one element, the element you removed.

Comment: What about if i want to remove the item at index 1 ?

Comment: do you really want to remove the elements from the first list?

Comment: Do i really want i think about it. The problem is i am new in kotlin. In swift that code returns what i want. İ meaan all the array except one item. But in kotlin it returns just one item that removed.

Comment: does swift also remove that particular item from the first list?

Comment: Yes in swift for example var arraytwo= arrayone.remove(at:2) returns all elements except one removed element

Comment: and what does the first list then contain?

Comment: Why and who gave -1 to my question. I think it is a fair question for a newbee

Comment: This is extremely unclear. Do you want to _copy_ the first list, and then **only** modify the copied list, do you want to copy the list and modify _both_, or do you want to modify the original list?

Comment: I just wanted to create a new list. Did not know i should have copied a list. Because in Swift you don’t need to copy. So as you see i try to create a new constant except one item in the list. So it is really clear for whom understands.

Comment: @Selcuk in Swift, arrays have value semantics. In Kotlin, arrays are _objects_, and are passed by reference. It would be hard to assume you want to do this by default.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

[`removeAt(0)`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-mutable-list/remove-at.html) removes the first element from the first list and returns it. [`arrayListOf`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/array-list-of.html) then uses that removed item to create a new (the second) list.

`arrayone` then contains: `b` and `c`. `arraytwo` then contains `a`.

You may want to use [`drop`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/drop.html) instead, if you didn't want to touch the first list and if you only wanted to add the remaining items to the new list, e.g.:

```
var arrayone: ArrayList<String> = arrayListOf("a","b","c")

val arraytwo = arrayone.drop(1)

for (item in arraytwo) {
  println(item) // now prints all except the first one...
}
// arrayone contains: a, b, c
// arraytwo contains: b, c
```

Or use [`dropLast(1)`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/drop-last.html) if you want to drop only the last item. Or use [`dropWhile`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/drop-while.html)/[`dropLastWhile`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/drop-last-while.html) if you have a condition to apply and drop all until/upto that condition...

If you really want to remove items from the first and add only the removed ones to the second list, then your current approach is ok. If you however wanted to remove items at specific index and have a new list instead just containing the not-removed ones, you need to construct a copy of the first list first and then apply your `removeAt` on that list, e.g.:

```
val arraytwo = arrayone.toMutableList().apply { 
  removeAt(0)
}
// or without the apply:
arraytwo.removeAt(0)
```

Or you may use [`filterIndexed`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/filter-indexed.html) to solve that:

```
val arraytwo = arrayone.filterIndexed { index, _ ->
  index != 1 // you can also specify more interesting filters here...
} // filter, map, etc. all return you a new list. If that list must be mutable again, just add a .toMutableList() at the end
```

By using `filterIndexed`, `filter`, `drop`, etc. you ensure that the first list is kept untouched. If you didn't want to touch the first list in the first place, you may rather want to use [`listOf`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/list-of.html) or [`toList`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/to-list.html), i.e. just a [`List`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-list/index.html) as type instead, which does not expose mutable functions (check also [Kotlin reference regarding Collections: List, Set, Map](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/collections.html)).

Maybe you are also interested in [`filter`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/filter.html)/[`filterNot`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/filter-not.html) and then soon in [`minus`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/minus.html) or similar functions to remove unwanted items without index.

Comment: But drop returns all but first n elements. So it is not usefull for example if i want to remove just third element

Comment: well... it depends... it wasn't that clear what you wanted to accomplish ;-) if you just want to omit elements, `drop` is ok... if you want to remove items... It basically depends on whether the first list is allowed to be changed or not...

Comment: İs not ArrayList mutable?

Comment: @Selcuk That's the entire point... you're removing from the _original list_, not from your copy. If you _don't_ want to copy the list, just do `arrayone.removeAt(0)` without another variable.

Comment: Ok got it. I need a copy to make a new one. And remove item from the copy. But i think it’s kind of weird. To make two process for such a simple situation. Thanks

Comment: As i said i am new to Kotlin. So i compare all the things with Swift. So sometimes it is hard to understand such situaions

Comment: That's fine... I on the other hand do not know Swift... so it's good to know how they differ... :-)

Comment: The more I think of it... if you do not want that the first list is altered, then please use an immutable variant of it... I added an approach using `filterIndexed`, which might also be something for you...

Answer (score 8):

`removeAt` returns the removed element:

> `abstract fun removeAt(index: Int): E (source)`
>
> Removes an element at the specified index from the list.
>
> **Return** the element that has been removed.
>   <sub>[kotlin.stdlib](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/index.html) / [kotlin.collections.MutableList.removeAt](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-mutable-list/remove-at.html)</sub>

You're making a new list with one element, the element you removed.

Try:

```
val arraytwo = ArrayList(arrayone) // Copy the list
arraytwo.removeAt(0)
```

You never clarified if you want to modify the original list. **If you do,** just do `arrayone.removeAt(0)`. That's it.

You can also make use of `apply`:

```
val arraytwo = ArrayList(arrayone).apply { removeAt(0) }
```

If you only need to remove items at the start or end, you can use [`drop`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/drop.html) (to remove items at the start) or [`dropLast`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/drop-last.html), but as far as I know there is no collection extension to drop an item in the middle of an iterable (and judging by your comment, you seem to need this.) This makes sense, since an iterable has no concept of size or index.

Answer (score 7):

If you just want to filter **one certain element** of your array you can use `.filterTo(destination, predicate)`.
For your example it can look like this:

```
val arrayone = arrayListOf<String>("a", "b", "c")
val arraytwo = arrayListOf<String>()

arrayone.filterTo(arraytwo, { it != "a" })

println(arrayone) //[a, b, c]
println(arraytwo) //[b, c]
```

Answer (score 7):

**For Normal ArrayList:**

```
val arrList = arrayListOf("account", "bec", "csw", "account")
arrList.removeAll { it == "account" }
```

**For Custom ArrayList:**

```
arrList.removeAll { it.key == "account" }
```

Answer (score 3):

try this ,

```
var arrayone: ArrayList<String> = arrayListOf("a","b","c")
arrayone.removeAt(0)
val arraytwo:ArrayList<String> = arrayListOf(arrayone)
for (item in arraytwo) {
  println(item)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
from import java.utils.ArrayList

ArrayList<YourCustomObject>.removeIf{yourCustomObject ->
     yourCustomObject.Id == IdToRemove
}
```

Comment: Your answer only contains code. I recommend that you don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Answer (score -1):

```
  val x = arrayListOf(1, 2, 3, 5)
  x.removeFirst()
  println(x)

  val y = x.filterIndexed { index, value -> index != 0 }
  println(y)
```

#### Output:

```
[2, 3, 5]
[3, 5]
```

GL

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46869060/5279996)